# ¿Sería correcto formular una pregunta pese a que no esté seguro de que el problema sea de programación?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Estoy realizando un Trabajo Fin de Grado que es un **modelo econométrico** y lo estoy desarrollando en R. El problema es que algunas de mis variables exógenas son **no significativas**, pese a que la literatura indica lo contrario, que esas variables deberían ser significativas. Por lo tanto, **no sé si el problema tiene un origen econométrico o de programación**, es decir, que no sé si he cometido algún error de programación o es un problema de teoría econométrica.

Además, para poder ayudarme sería necesario que aquel que lo intente acceda a mi repositorio de github donde tengo todo el código y la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando. Entonces, ¿Sería correcto colgar este tipo de preguntas en [es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com)? No lo tengo claro ya que no puedo asegurar que el problema sea de programación y , a parte, dada la índole del problema no es posible formular una pregunta con un ejemplo reproducible, es necesario acceder a mi repositorio([github.com/perfydio/Proyecto-ENS](https://github.com/perfydio/Proyecto-ENS)).

Salud y ánimos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la pregunta

> ¿Sería correcto formular una pregunta pese a que no esté seguro de que el problema sea de programación?

Depende. Sería correcto si eres capaz de expresar la pregunta siguiendo los lineamientos indicados en [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Por lo que cuentas del caso, me parece que todavía tienes mucho trabajo por hacer para llegar a un [ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Si bien no es necesario que todas las preguntas incluyan uno, si en este caso en realidad no fuera posible, lo más probable es que la pregunta sería demasiado amplia para este sitio.

Comment: Creo que sí sería capaz de elaborar una buena pregunta tal y como he ido haciendo, así que intentaré trabajar en mi código hasta llegar a un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable. Aunque me temo que esto no es posible sin requerir  que para poder ayudarme sea necesario emplear la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando y, por lo tanto, efectivamente la pregunta sería demasiado amplia para este sitio.

Comment: Podrías dividir el problema en varias preguntas, por ejemplo quizás una sobre algún aspecto del modelo, otra sobre cómo ese aspecto del modelo se refleja en la base de datos, otra sobre cómo se calcula algo asumiendo que el modelo y su implementación son correctos... En cualquier caso, te sugiero esperar un poco a ver si alguien que suela participar en preguntas sobre R te puede dar una orientación más precisa.  Tip: Revisa en la información de la etiquetas relacionadas quienes son los usuarios más activos y revisa sus perfiles por si tienen indicaciones sobre cómo contactarlos

Comment: y/o pregunta por ellos en el [chat].